# Invalid Login attempt while accessing Netsuite using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, netsuite

I am attempting to make a "POST" request in Google Apps Script to send information to Netsuite and create a record. However, when I execute the script, Netsuite returns a 403 error code.

This is my code:

```
let data = {"id": id}
let options = { 
  'method': 'post', 
  'contentType': 'application/json', 
  'payload': JSON.stringify({'data': data}),
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'OAuth realm="xxx",oauth_consumer_key="xxx",oauth_token="xxx",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="xxx",oauth_nonce="xxx",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="xxx"'},
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('url', options)
```

I obtained the authorization data from Postman and wrote it into the headers. Can someone please review my code and tell me what I am doing wrong, or provide me with an example code for reference?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Netsuite access ? If so you can go to setup> user/ roles > login audit trail and use advanced search to see the exact details of the failed login attempt to Netsuite .

All this taking into account you have created an integration and the access tokens for it .

Other than that , you can’t copy paste time stamp and nonce from postman to your headers . You have to generate them. You can check oauth.js